# Text Field keyboard set to Number Pad but regular keyboard is displaying on selection

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xamarin

I have set my text field's keyboard to 'Number Pad' in the xcode designer which adds the following code between my  tags in my .xib

```
<textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"
autocorrectionType="no" keyboardType="numberPad"/>
```

I had expected that when selecting this textfield, the following keyboard input would appear:

[image]

But instead, the following input is appearing:

[image]

How can i set my text field to use the first input (or similar) instead of the second?

Comment: Use the `Phone Pad` instead of the `Number Pad`.

Comment: You should use `phonePad` not `numberPad`, you are using `numberPad now.`

Comment: sorry, i wrote it wrong the first time, i meant to say that setting it to phonePad still uses the second input

Comment: Are you on a iPad? There is no phone pad available on this device … So the displayed keyboard layout with numbers is correct.

Comment: OH, that hadn't crossed my mind! That's a downer. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You could post your answer to help other people with the problem.

Comment: or you could post it and i'll mark as answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `yourTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad` if you are on a iPhone. iPad's do not support this type of keyboard. An iPad will display the NumberPad.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `keyboardType` property of `UITextFiled` to `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad` as follows:

```
yourTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
```

Comment: Or in the XML use `keyboardType="phonePad"`

Comment: i'm using xamarin and c# so my code looks like:
this.txtInput.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad;

Which i've put in ViewDidLoad but this still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

As of **Swift 3**, it is now a little different. For a UITextField, e.g. height, it'll be like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!

height.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
```

OR

```
height.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

Now when you press the text field, proper keyboard will popup.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

In viewDidLoad write -

```
    mobileTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

you can get more choices in `UIKeyboardType`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on iOS 7 use following code :

```
self.valueField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```